# How to define hidden field widget and set up value into modelform and save it in DB?

Tags: python, django

I have such models.py

```
class User_information(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And my forms.py

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User_information
        fields = ['name', 'url']
        labels = {
            'name': _('Имя'),
            'url': _('link'),
        }
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 3}),
          # 'url' : ?????????????
        }
```

I need to save a current url page from hidden field of form. How can I set up hidden field and get current url of form's page and save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can render your form manually and specifying the hidden attribute manually:

[How to render form manually](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html)

Then there is `HiddenInput` input from `django.forms` ([HiddenInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput)) which you can specify like:

```
    widgets = {
        'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 3}),
        'url' : forms.HiddenInput
    }
```

Comment: Got it. Added HiddenInput. Is it only way to render form manually to add values to ModeForm field?

Comment: @question1 You have to provide initial data to the form in view like `form = PostForm(initial={'name': 'name to be provided', 'url': 'any initial url'})`